# notepad++ search only folders named "example" in a given directory

Tags: notepad++

Im trying to use notepad++ to search for a Global variable inside folders with a certain name in a given directory

how do I specify the folder name ?

This is for a large amount of TFS files and Im trying to lower my search results by specifying the folder names

Comment: Have you Googled for this before asking? ... https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-use-the-find-in-files-feature-in-notepad.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm quite certain the question is about limiting search to any folders with a certain name. Afaik that is not supported.

Comment: @Kapep Hmm...I think Cygwin or some similar tool what can emulate Linux commands might help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the folder to search here:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Then give the folder name you want to search in.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to specify a single folder (which may be searched recursively). According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2433#issuecomment-254522056), the "Filter" field of the "Find in files" feature only supports file name wildcards and the filter is not applied to the path but only the file name.

This means you either need to find/create a plugin for Notepad++ that does this or find some other applications or commands for searching in specific folders.

If you *really* want to keep using Notepad++ for this, it should also be possible to write a script that searches for the desired folders and creates symlinks to those folders. You could then simply use the N++ file search in the folder where the symlinks are.